# Angular not detecting change when calling array.sort()

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, angular8, angular9

I have an array of objects that i display using an "*ngFor" loop, when i call array.sort() changes occurs inside the array and the position/order of the elements changes but angular doesn't detect the changes and doesn't re-fires the "ngFor" loop. how can i update my UI after calling the sort function.

Comment: you have to sort and reassign the object to the `ngFor`, because `sort` creates a new instance of the array

Comment: @Aravind no it's the opposite, `sort` doesn't create a new instance of the array. But re-assigning the variable to itself will let Angular understand that the template must be updated, so that's the solution

Comment: @Aravind `sort` sorts the array in-place.

Comment: @charbel - Is the array passed to the component by data binding? You should show the relevant code in the question.

Answer (score 8):

If `a` is your array, then try:

```
this.a = [...this.a.sort()];
```